# Angular 7, How to handle several calls to a asp.net web api

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm learning angular 7 and i try to load several list of objects from a asp.net web api. The weird thing is i can get one list but not the other if i disable one of the call, but i can't get both list at loading time. Here is my code :

my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackerManagerService } from '../../services/tracker-manager.service';
import { AirlineManagerService } from '../../services/airline-manager.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './tracker-selection.component.html'
})
export class TrackerSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  public TrackerAddModal;

  trackers: any = [];
  airlines: any = [];

  constructor(public airlineManagerService: AirlineManagerService,
    public trackerManagerService: TrackerManagerService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllTrackers();
    this.getAllAirlines();
  }

  getAllTrackers() {
    this.trackers = [];
    this.trackerManagerService.getAllTrackers().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.trackers = data;
});

  }

  getAllAirlines() {


       this.airlines = [];
this.airlineManagerService.getAllAirlines().subscribe((test: any[]) => {
      console.log(test);
      this.airlines = test;
    });
      }

}
```

my tracker service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const endpoint = //Some http url;
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TrackerManagerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log(res);
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  getAllTrackers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(endpoint + 
   'tracker');//.pipe(map(this.extractData));
 }
}
```

my airline service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const endpoint = //Some http url;
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AirlineManagerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log(res);
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  getAllAirlines(): Observable<any[]> {
     return this.http.get<any[]>(endpoint + 
    'airline');//.pipe(map(this.extractData));
  }
}
```

If i try to make the two calls i get this error in console:
Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I updated my code to precise that i want to return an array. I don't have an error anymore but i can't get the two lists, only one of them. Maybe because i call the same web api but different functions at the same time?

Comment: Your service returns an object, but you expect an array. When you do ngFor on an object you will get that error.

Comment: That's an HTML error because you have used `*ngFor` on an object. Declare your data as an array, and return an empty array by default.

Comment: @CornelC How can i do that?

Comment: @trichetriche also why each call works well alone but not together?

Comment: @NicolasDaumalle Don't know, going to need a [mcve] to answer you on that

Answer (score 0):

Your service returns an object, but you expect an array. When you do `ngFor` on an object you will get that error.

You are declaring arrays :

```
trackers: any = [];
airlines: any = [];
```

but you assign objects to them:

```
this.trackerManagerService.getAllTrackers().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.trackers = data;
    });

this.airlineManagerService.getAllAirlines().subscribe((test: {}) => {
      console.log(test);
      this.airlines = test;
    });
```

I am not sure what your API returns but the signature of the service should be

```
getAllTrackers(): Observable<any[]>
getAllAirlines(): Observable<any[]>
```

Comment: i retrieve a json string like that: : [{"Id":1,"Name":"AAA","FullName":"Ansett Australia"},{"Id":223,"Name":"AAB","FullName":""},{"Id":224,"Name":"AAC","FullName":""},....]

Comment: "i retrieve a json string", try using JSON.parse(this.extractData). If it's truly a JSON string, then ngFor has no idea what to do with that string data until it's parsed.@NicolasDaumalle